# Find the jacobian

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, determinant

I'm been struggling with the problem for a quite some time now.
I need to find the jacobian for the following :

$$u=x-y$$
$$v=xy$$

What I did :

$$x=y+u\\x=\frac{v}{y}\\y=x-u\\y=\frac{v}{x}$$

\begin{vmatrix}
dx/du & dx/dv \\ 
dy/du & dy/dv 
\end{vmatrix}

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{y} \\ 
-1 & \frac{1}{x} 
\end{vmatrix}

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$

But for some reason the answer say I should get : $$\frac{1}{x+y}$$

The method they used in the book is to calculate $J^{-1}$ which is $x+y$ and use the law $J(x,y)*J(u,v)=1$ in order to get $J(u,v)=\frac{1}{x+y}$

I don't know, why I get different answer.

Any idea?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The simple mnemonic is this:

**When ever you are computing the Jacobian, elements of the same coordinate system must go on the same side of the equality sign**

What you did wrong: writing $x = y + u$ etc.

---

When computing $\partial x / \partial u$ in computing the Jacobian, you are asked to compute "the partial derivative of $x$ relative to varying $u$ while keeping $v$ fixed, when $x$ is seen as a function of $u$ and $v$."

So the expression

$$ x = y + u$$

really should mean

$$ x(u,v) = y(u,v) + u $$

since **you need to express the function $x$ as a function of $u$ and $v$**. So when you compute
$ \partial x / \partial u $ what you should end up with from the equation above is

$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} + 1 $$

(you arrived at 1, which is the result of "the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to varying $u$ if $y$ is kept fixed", since $y$ and $v$ are not the same, what you computed is **not** the correct thing).

---

In these kinds of situations a helpful book keeping trick is the one that physicists use often in thermodynamics:

instead of writing $\partial x / \partial u$, you can write $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} |_{v}$ to remind yourself that the partial derivative with respect to $u$ is taken with $v$ held fixed, and nothing else. So when computing, when $\partial_u$ acts on anything that is not $u$, and $v$, you must apply the chain rule.

---

Edit: after saying what you shouldn't do, let me say what you should do.

Starting with 
$$ x + y = u$$
and
$$ xy = v$$
Taking the partials relative to $u$ (while holding $v$ fixed!!!) is 
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 1 $$
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} y + x \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 0$$
and taking the partials relative to $v$ you get
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} y + x \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = 1 $$
which, treating $x$ and $y$ as "knowns", is a system of four equations for four unknowns. Solving this system you will get the partials as functions of $x,y$ and from that you can compute the Jacobian. As you can see now that the method of computing $J^{-1}$ is computationally simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!, I tried to calculate $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} + 1$$. But I get $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=-1+1=0$ Therefore it's impossible to get $x+y$ out of the jacobian, Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you substitute $-1$ for $\partial y / \partial u$? The same comment about $\partial x /\partial u$ being wrong applies to your computation of $\partial y/\partial u$.

Comment: I don't think I completely understood how you managed to get: $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 1$$

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial y(u,v)}{{\partial u}}+\frac{u}{du}=\frac{\partial (x-u)}{{\partial u}}+\frac{u}{du}=-1+1=0$$

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial u}+\frac{u}{du}=\frac{\partial (u+y)}{\partial u}+\frac{u}{du}=1+1=2$$

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=2$$

Comment: Lines 2, 3, and 4 in your last comment are entire nonsense. Like I said, start with $x(u,v) + y(u,v) = u$ Take $\partial / \partial u$ on both sides. What do you get? (Use the property that the derivative of a sum of functions is the sum of the derivatives on the left hand side. The right hand side is the function $f(u,v) = u$, what is its partial derivative with respect to $u$?)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution (Alternative Way):

We were given the transformation
$$u=x-y$$
$$v=xy$$

Notice that rewriting the equations in terms of $x$ and $y$ will make things harder (since you cannot solve for $x$ and $y$ explicitly.) However, we invoke the idea that
$$J(u,v) J(x,y)=1$$

Thus instead of finding $J(u,v)$, we try to compute $J(x,y)$ since we already have explicit expressions for $u$ and $v$.
$$J(x,y)=\left | \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} \right |=\begin{vmatrix}
u_x &u_y \\ 
v_x &v_y 
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 &-1 \\ 
y &x 
\end{vmatrix}=x-(-y)=x+y$$

Therefore
$$J(u,v)=\frac{1}{J(x,y)}=\frac{1}{x+y}$$

Comment: This is indeed how I would compute the Jacobian myself. But it is also the "book solution" that the OP mentioned. I think the OP's question is more about why what he did wasn't equal to this solution here.